# Don't show 'clear all filters' on the flag summary page unless there's an active filter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

The new ability to filter my flag history is awesome, but the 'clear all filters' button seems out of place when I'm not filtering anything:

[image]

Can we hide this unless there's an active filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When no filters are in play, the link will be disabled.

With you in the next build.